# Посоветуйте алгоритм сжатия изображений

Tags: сжатие

Небольшая предыстория:

Очень давно прочитал статью типа : Художник из Германии сделал свой алгоритм сжатия изображений.

Перешёл по ссылке и там был довольно приятный сайт, на который я ради интереса загрузил full-hd картинку, после недолгого сжатия мне выдало картинку, на которой почти не виднелась разница, но размер был уменьшен в 10-20 раз (могу ошибаться, но точно помню, что сжатие было ОЧЕНЬ сильным).

Если кто-нибудь тоже видел этот сайт, прошу, дайте ссылку, сейчас я критически нуждаюсь в нём.

P.S. Та статься называлась не так, но суть похожая: "Кто-то, откуда-то сделал свой алгоритм сжатия изображений" (примерно так).

Comment: А смотрели вы эту картинку чем? Браузером или одним из просмотрщиков изображений? Дык они понимают только стандартные форматы и не смогли бы открыть незнакомый. Или вы с того сайта сперва скачали программу-просмотрщик файлов этого формата?

Comment: Я точно не помню, но по-моему я просто загрузил .jpg, подождал и скачал .jpg, без изменения разрешения и качества

Comment: jpg - это стандартный давно известный формат, но никак не новый. Кстати, у этого формата есть разные степени сжатия. Естественно, чем сильнее сжатие (файл меньше), тем хуже качество изображения.

Comment: Если некто и разработал свой формат, то, чтобы другие им могли пользоваться, нужно либо предоставить им программу-просмотрщик, либо конвертировать из него в известные форматы (то есть все плюсы потеряются).